# Occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons

Tags: android, debugging, react-native, dependencies, adb

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:_debugPublishCopy'.

[image]